# MSBuild generate files in d:\target, but not d:\target\_PublishedWebsites

Tags: msbuild

When I use msbuild to build a web site project under command line
msbuild website1.sln /property:OutDir=d:\target\

I just want the published files generated in directory d:\target, but not D:\target_PublishedWebsites.

What can I do for that?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way those .targets files are created it's pretty tough to get that to work. Your best bet is to let it publish there, copy the files and then delete the directory.